# How to ask the user to add the logged in details after some time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my website i want to implement the functionality of re-login after the page sits idle for some time. I mean when user opens the page and left the page for some time and doing some other work. when the user comes again i need to again ask the credentials of the user. How can it be done.

Comment: u can use cookies and set the expiration time of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to check session on all pages or other options is use Asp.net Membership